# Is there a prime number $p$ such that : $p\bmod n =1 $ for $n <10$? and if yes , Are there infinity of them?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primality-test

I want to know set of primes such that satisfies the below question :

> **Question:**
>   Is there a prime number $p$ such that : $p\equiv 1\bmod n $ for **all** $n <10$ ? And if yes, are there infinity of them ?

For example :  $p\bmod 1 =1 ,p\bmod 2 =1,p\bmod 3 =1,\cdots$

**Edit**: I have added a question includes wether there are infinity of them without changing the meaning of the question

Comment: but 3 mod 9 not equal 1 and 3 mod 8 is not 1

Comment: Do you mean $p\equiv 1 \pmod n$ for each $n\in \{2,\cdots, 9\}$ ?  But the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that this is the same as $n\equiv 1 \pmod {2^3\times 3^2\times 5 \times 7}$ and by Dirichlet there are infinitely many such primes.

Comment: I have edited for **all** $n<10$. I suppose this is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a number is congruent to $1$ mod each of $1,2,3,4,...,10$ if and only if it is $1$ mod $2520$. In fact $2521$ is prime so this will do.

Comment: Thanks, now the question w'd be important if we ask wether there are infinity of them

Comment: @zeraouliarafik  as remarked in the comments, [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) tells us there are infinitely many.  In fact, the density of such primes is positive, and equal to $\frac 1{\varphi(2520)}=0.001736\overline 1$.